# Recyclerview item-height changes after loading data

Tags: android, layout, android-recyclerview, placeholder

I use text spans in my app with ImageSpan and text. The text is parsed asynchronously and the ImageSpans are inserted/replaced accordingly. There might be one or more ImageSpans or none at all.

How can I calculate the size beforehand which the final text will take up with ImageSpans included?

The problem I have is, When I finally update the TextView in the RecyclerView item, the whole view "jumps". You can imagine with a lot of list items which are set at different times, the list would appear to be jumping.

[image]

I want to eliminate the "jump" by pre-setting the size of the TextView for when the text is displayed, the size of the item is not changed and the list doesn't jump.

Any help or suggestions would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since we have no idea about the size of text being loaded before it completes, the only option we have is to **leave some area reserved** for that text.[image: Illustration: before and after loading]

This can easily be done by making either the TextView or one of it's parent (which is not the parent of known texts) fixed sized.

## These are also recommended:

- Make the text [ellipsized](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:ellipsize).
- Set a place-holder.

The placeholder can be simple dummy text or something more elegant like as in the image below.

[image: Skeleton library preview]

*You can find this library [here](https://github.com/ethanhua/Skeleton)*.

Comment: Thank you, this actually helped me a lot. I have an idea to measure the pre-parsed text then set the TextView size to the measurement. The parsed text shouldn't be much bigger than that.

Comment: I'm glad I could help :-)

Answer (score 0):

I have eventually gotten this to calculate the widths and heights of the child views in runtime(onLayout) by creating a custom element.

This view is a text and date layout, it calculates the text part and prevents the text to overlap the date in the right bottom corner:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;

public class TextDateLayout extends FrameLayout {
    private EmojiTextView lblMessage;
    private LinearLayout llDateWrapper;

    private LayoutParams lblMessageLayoutParams;
    private int lblMessageWidth;
    private int lblMessageHeight;

    private LayoutParams llDateWrapperLayoutParams;
    private int llDateWrapperWidth;
    private int llDateWrapperHeight;

    public TextDateLayout(@NonNull Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public TextDateLayout(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public TextDateLayout(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        try {
            super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

            lblMessage = (EmojiTextView) getChildAt(0);
            llDateWrapper = (LinearLayout) getChildAt(1);

            int widthSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
            int pWidthSize = widthSize;

            if (lblMessage == null || llDateWrapper == null || widthSize <= 0) return;

            int availableWidth = widthSize - getPaddingLeft() - getPaddingRight();

            lblMessageLayoutParams = (LayoutParams) lblMessage.getLayoutParams();
            lblMessageWidth = lblMessage.getMeasuredWidth() + lblMessageLayoutParams.leftMargin + lblMessageLayoutParams.rightMargin;
            lblMessageHeight = lblMessage.getMeasuredHeight() + lblMessageLayoutParams.topMargin + lblMessageLayoutParams.bottomMargin;

            llDateWrapperLayoutParams = (LayoutParams) llDateWrapper.getLayoutParams();
            llDateWrapperWidth = llDateWrapper.getMeasuredWidth() + llDateWrapperLayoutParams.leftMargin + llDateWrapperLayoutParams.rightMargin;
            llDateWrapperHeight = llDateWrapper.getMeasuredHeight() + llDateWrapperLayoutParams.topMargin + llDateWrapperLayoutParams.bottomMargin;

            int lblMessageLineCount = lblMessage.getLineCount();
            float lblMessageLastLineWidth = lblMessageLineCount > 0 ? lblMessage.getLayout().getLineWidth(lblMessageLineCount - 1) : 0;

            widthSize = getPaddingLeft() + getPaddingRight();
            int heightSize = getPaddingTop() + getPaddingBottom();

            if (lblMessageLineCount > 1 && lblMessageLastLineWidth + llDateWrapperWidth < lblMessage.getMeasuredWidth()) {
                widthSize += lblMessageWidth;
                heightSize += lblMessageHeight;
            } else if (lblMessageLineCount > 1 && lblMessageLastLineWidth + llDateWrapperWidth > availableWidth) {
                widthSize += lblMessageWidth;
                heightSize += lblMessageHeight + llDateWrapperHeight;
            } else if (lblMessageLineCount == 1 && lblMessageWidth + llDateWrapperWidth > pWidthSize) {
                widthSize = pWidthSize;
                heightSize += lblMessageHeight + llDateWrapperHeight;
            } else if (lblMessageLineCount == 1 && lblMessageWidth + llDateWrapperWidth < getMeasuredWidth()) {
                widthSize = getMeasuredWidth();
                heightSize += lblMessageHeight;
            } else {
                widthSize += lblMessageWidth + llDateWrapperWidth;
                heightSize += lblMessageHeight;
            }

            widthMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(widthSize, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
            heightMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(heightSize, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);

        } catch (Exception ex) {
        }

        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
        super.onLayout(changed, left, top, right, bottom);

        if (lblMessage == null || llDateWrapper == null) return;

        lblMessage.layout(getPaddingLeft(),
                getPaddingTop(),
                lblMessage.getWidth() + getPaddingLeft(),
                lblMessage.getHeight() + getPaddingTop());
    }
}
```

Using it will look like this:

```
<com.app.element.TextDateLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="2dp">

    <com.app.element.EmojiTextView
        android:id="@+id/lblMessage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        app:emojiSize="25dp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical">

        <com.app.element.TextView
            android:id="@+id/lblTimestamp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="9sp"
            android:textColor="@color/black" />

    </LinearLayout>

</com.app.element.TextDateLayout>
```

The `EmojiTextView`:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.text.SpannableStringBuilder;
import android.util.AttributeSet;

import androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView;

import com.app.R;
import com.app.helpers.EmojiHelper;

public class EmojiTextView extends AppCompatTextView {
    private int emojiSize;

    public EmojiTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(null);
    }

    public EmojiTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(attrs);
    }

    public EmojiTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init(attrs);
    }

    private void init(AttributeSet attrs) {
        if (attrs != null) {
            TypedArray a = getContext().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.EmojiTextView);
            emojiSize = (int) a.getDimension(R.styleable.EmojiTextView_emojiSize, getTextSize());
            a.recycle();
        } else {
            emojiSize = (int) getTextSize();
        }

        setText(getText());
    }

    @Override
    public void setText(CharSequence text, BufferType type) {
        if (text != null && text.length() > 0) {
            SpannableStringBuilder builder = new SpannableStringBuilder(text);
            EmojiHelper.getInstance().parseForEmojis(builder, emojiSize); //This takes the string and parses the Emojis, replacing the text with ImageSpans
            super.setText(builder, type);
        } else {
            super.setText(text, type);
        }
    }
}
```

Attributes for the `EmojiTextView`:

```
<resources>

    <!--Emojis-->
    <attr name="emojiSize" format="dimension" />

    <declare-styleable name="EmojiTextView">
        <attr name="emojiSize" />
    </declare-styleable>

</resources>
```

For an example to parse Emojis from Unicode Characters, take a look at this link:
https://github.com/ankushsachdeva/emojicon/blob/70bdd3731ebfc12a973d4125f5c5598015d96a62/lib/src/github/ankushsachdeva/emojicon/EmojiconHandler.java#L1396

*Small Snippet in-case the link doesn't work anymore:*

```
public static void addEmojis(Context context, Spannable text, int emojiSize, int index, int length) {
    int textLength = text.length();
    int textLengthToProcessMax = textLength - index;
    int textLengthToProcess = length < 0 || length >= textLengthToProcessMax ? textLength : (length+index);

    // remove spans throughout all text
    EmojiconSpan[] oldSpans = text.getSpans(0, textLength, EmojiconSpan.class);
    for (int i = 0; i < oldSpans.length; i++) {
        text.removeSpan(oldSpans[i]);
    }

    int skip;
    for (int i = index; i < textLengthToProcess; i += skip) {
        skip = 0;
        int icon = 0;
        char c = text.charAt(i);
        if (isSoftBankEmoji(c)) {
            icon = getSoftbankEmojiResource(c);
            skip = icon == 0 ? 0 : 1;
        }

        if (icon == 0) {
            int unicode = Character.codePointAt(text, i);
            skip = Character.charCount(unicode);

            if (unicode > 0xff) {
                icon = getEmojiResource(context, unicode);
            }

            if (icon == 0 && i + skip < textLengthToProcess) {
                int followUnicode = Character.codePointAt(text, i + skip);
                if (followUnicode == 0x20e3) {
                    int followSkip = Character.charCount(followUnicode);
                    switch (unicode) {
                        //...
                    }
                    skip += followSkip;
                } else {
                    int followSkip = Character.charCount(followUnicode);
                    switch (unicode) {
                        //...
                    }
                    skip += followSkip;
                }
            }
        }

        if (icon > 0) {
            text.setSpan(new EmojiconSpan(context, icon, emojiSize), i, i + skip, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        }
    }
}
```